# garbage value added to vector following a sort operation

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a `vector` called keys, for sorting which, I have `struct comp` :

```
typedef std::list<std::vector<WayPoint> >::iterator pathIt;
typedef std::pair<double, pathIt> Pair;
struct comp{
    bool operator()(const Pair& lhs,const Pair& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.first*1000000 <= rhs.first*1000000;
    }
};
std::list<std::vector<WayPoint> > paths;
std::vector<Pair> keys;
```

during the program, I have a `std::sort` operation on `keys`:

```
std::sort(keys.begin(), keys.end(),comp());
```

I printed the container (first value of `Pair` elements) before and after `sort` and noticed that some garbage is added to `keys` after the sort.
Am I doing something wrong in the `compare function` ? 
Note: I figured in the comp function, multiplying by 1000000 would be a good way to compare doubles to a good enough degree. right?

thanks

**UPDATE:**
Beside the problem with `<=` in the comparator which had to be replaced with `<`, I need more clarification regarding comparison of double values: May be I am confused but why are there so many questions in SO analysing the methods for comparing `double` values? If processor can correctly compare doubles, why is it strictly recommended not to use `double` as key in `std::map` ? Am I confusing two unrelated topics? was the above multiplication **`Unnecessary`** or **`A wrong way to implement a necessary requirement`**?

Comment: Why did you multiply by 1000000 on both sides to calculate an inequality?

Comment: I thought It would not be able to compare doubles otherwise

Comment: The processor knows how to compare doubles to full precision; there's no need to scale them.

Comment: OK, but even commenting that multiplication doesnt solve the issue.

Comment: A comparison operator for sort needs to return true when `<`, not `<=`, and if you could have `==` `.first` values you should fall back on `.second` to give some ordering.

Comment: next time you want to write 1 million in double, use `1e6` notation.

Comment: Also note that doing the multiplication will have the peculiar effect of rounding numbers that were different before the multiplication, to some value that is now the same on both side if the difference is dim. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: You definitely need to fix your comparator. Sorting and sorted-containers in the standard library adhere to a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) as-related to your comparator, which is *your* definition of "less".  Among the attributes of a SWO, given `a` and `b`, if `!(a < b || b < a)` then `a` and  `b` are equivalent. By returning `true` when items are equal, you munge that logic flow.

Comment: @TonyD and everybody else, thanks for your comments. Yes the `<=` was the culprit and replacing it with `<` solved the issue(beside removing the multiplication). BTW to me `<` is enough for case of equal values. right?

Comment: ONE MORE QUESTION from all those who pointed on my wrong multiplication: May be I am confused but why are there so many questions analysing the methods for comparing `double` values? Why is it strictly recommended not to use `double` as key in `std::map` ? am I confusing two unrelated topics? was the above multiplication `unnecessary` or `a wrong way to implement a necessary requirement`?

Comment: `double`s are stored with limited precision (15-16 significant digits), and are often approximations of the mathematical value you've logically calculated.  For example, in maths .1 + .2 == .4 - .1, but that may not be true when using doubles.  Indeed, .1 + .2 might not yield the same double value when the .1 and .2 are sometimes calculated at compile time, and other times calculated at run time or after other operations (on Intel, partly because 80-bit floating point registers on the CPU might be rounded down to 64-bit floats for in-memory storage at different times).

Comment: All this means that if you put something in a list or map with a specific `double` key, you might not find it again if you search with what you think is the same value because the 15th or 16th significant digit differs.  A classic work on the issue that you should read is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little test program to see if I could reproduce your issue, and it works fine for me. I wonder if maybe the garbage is being introduced some other way, perhaps when you're printing the contents of the vector. Here's my test code:

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct WayPoint {
    int x;
    WayPoint(int x);
};

typedef std::vector<WayPoint> Path;
typedef std::list<Path> PathList;
typedef std::pair<double,PathList::iterator> Pair;
typedef std::vector<Pair> PairList;

struct PairComp {

    bool operator()(const Pair& lhs, const Pair& rhs ) const {
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
    }

};

int main(void) {

    PathList pathList{
        Path{WayPoint(1),WayPoint(2),WayPoint(3)},
        Path{WayPoint(4),WayPoint(5),WayPoint(6)},
        Path{WayPoint(7),WayPoint(8),WayPoint(9)},
        Path{WayPoint(10),WayPoint(11),WayPoint(12)}
    };

    PathList::iterator pathListIt = pathList.begin();
    Pair pair1{7.0,pathListIt++};
    Pair pair2{2.0,pathListIt++};
    Pair pair3{14.0,pathListIt++};
    Pair pair4{9.0,pathListIt++};
    PairList pairList{pair1,pair2,pair3,pair4};

    std::sort(pairList.begin(), pairList.end(), PairComp() );

    for (PairList::iterator it = pairList.begin(); it != pairList.end(); ++it) {
        Pair& pair = *it;
        std::printf("%f\n", pair.first );
    } // end for

} // end main()

WayPoint::WayPoint(int x) : x(x) {}
```

Output:

```
2.000000
7.000000
9.000000
14.000000
```

Let me know what you're doing differently than I am, to see if we can figure out what might be causing the problem.

**Edit:** Ok, here's a modified program that uses the incorrect comparison operator and guarantees many duplicates:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct WayPoint {
    int x;
    WayPoint(int x);
};

typedef std::vector<WayPoint> Path;
typedef std::list<Path> PathList;
typedef std::pair<double,PathList::iterator> Pair;
typedef std::vector<Pair> PairList;

struct PairComp {

    bool operator()(const Pair& lhs, const Pair& rhs ) const {
        return lhs.first <= rhs.first;
    }

};

double getKey(void);

const int NUM = 30;

int main(void) {

    std::srand(time(0));

    PathList pathList;
    PairList pairList;

    pathList.push_back(Path({WayPoint(0)}));
    PathList::iterator it = pathList.begin();
    pairList.push_back(Pair(getKey(), it ));
    for (int i = 1; i < NUM; ++i) {
        pathList.push_back(Path({WayPoint(i)}));
        pairList.push_back(Pair(getKey(), ++it ));
    } // end for

    std::sort(pairList.begin(), pairList.end(), PairComp() );

    for (PairList::iterator it = pairList.begin(); it != pairList.end(); ++it) {
        Pair& pair = *it;
        std::printf("%f\n", pair.first );
    } // end for

} // end main()

WayPoint::WayPoint(int x) : x(x) {}

double getKey(void) {
    static double sample[] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0};
    return sample[std::rand()%(sizeof(sample)/sizeof(sample[0]))];
} // end getKey()
```

It works for me, example output:

```
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
3.000000
3.000000
3.000000
3.000000
4.000000
4.000000
4.000000
4.000000
5.000000
5.000000
5.000000
5.000000
5.000000
5.000000
6.000000
6.000000
7.000000
8.000000
8.000000
8.000000
```

**Edit:** Aha! I ran the modified version of the test program MANY times, and eventually got a segfault in `PairComp::operator()`, as called from `std::sort()`. Here's the complete backtrace from gdb (warning: verbose C++ backtrace follows):

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000100402144 in PairComp::operator()(std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > const&, std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > const&) const ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000100402144 in PairComp::operator()(std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > const&, std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > const&) const ()
#1  0x0000000100401f87 in bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp>::operator()<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >) ()
#2  0x00000001004042ea in __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > > std::__unguarded_partition<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp> >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp>) ()
#3  0x0000000100404852 in __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > > std::__unguarded_partition_pivot<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp> >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp>) ()
#4  0x00000001004041cd in void std::__introsort_loop<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, long, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp> >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, long, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp>) ()
#5  0x00000001004041f0 in void std::__introsort_loop<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, long, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp> >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, long, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp>) ()
#6  0x0000000100404b9e in void std::__sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp> >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<PairComp>) ()
#7  0x00000001004049e4 in void std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, PairComp>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >*, std::vector<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<double, std::_List_iterator<std::vector<WayPoint, std::allocator<WayPoint> > > > > > >, PairComp) ()
#8  0x00000001004012e8 in main ()
```

I also ran the modified program many times but with the correct (`<`) comparison operator, and it never segfaulted. So I think we've identified the problem: the incorrect comparison operator.

I guess the general lesson here is that when you violate a requirement on which a blind (trusting) algorithm depends, all bets are off. It could introduce garbage data, it could segfault, or it could give you the correct result. You've gotta be careful.

This was a fun problem to work on, +1 for the question. :)

Comment: Try putting in matching elements. All of your values differ.

Comment: Did I do something wrong here? I think I got a downvote (before had +1 for this answer), and now this answer is listed as -2 on my profile, not sure why... haven't gotten any feedback.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Looks like a helpful answer to me. Only thing I'd suggest is that it's more beneficial to discuss actual correctness than "this is what my compiler does" because UB is a spooky thing.

Comment: It could be because you lead with something that is wrong. It doesn't constitute a good answer to the question. It is more a record of the process you took to figure something out.

Comment: Actually that's a good point. This is presented in blog format ;) Narrow it down to just the correct part.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator function is incorrect. It calculates less-than-or-equals. A comparator must strictly calculate less-than. If your vector contains multiple elements with the same value, this could cause errors.

I do not know if that is the source of your garbage but it is the first thing I would fix. Let me know in a comment if that does not help.

Additionally, as stated in the comments, the multiplication in the comparator is totally unnecessary.